# Message object .edit() stops working after some time

Tags: discord.js

First I create an object

```
var queue = {1:{},2:{},3:{}};
```

And then I store the message based on QueueKey, or edit if it's already created

```
        if (typeof queue[QueueKey].messageOBJ == 'undefined')
        {
            queue[QueueKey].messageOBJ = await configChannel.send({ embeds: [getEmbedFloor(QueueKey)] });  
        }
        else
        {
            queue[QueueKey].messageOBJ = await queue[QueueKey].messageOBJ.edit({ embeds: [getEmbedFloor(QueueKey)] });
        }
```

everything starts working well but after sometime(1~2 hours) bot stops editing the already created message, looks like it lose object reference.
It not pops any error message or code break, seems like the message was edited sucessfully but the real message in discord still the same

I'm thinking in store the messageID instead the whole object and search for the message ID with .fetch() but this will lead to other problems

is there any way to store message Objects properly?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my problem, actually bot was editing the message to frequently, so after some time discord "auto ban" my bot for some time, something like a cooldown, só it starts to get slower and slower, up to seems like it is stuck.

My solution was check message before edit, to compare if the changes in message are really necessary, before edit or not